Penrose condition and the pseudoinverse
How can i prove that given two linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ and $U : W\rightarrow V$ on $V,W$ finite dimensional vector spaces, such that $TUT = T$ , $UTU = U$, and both $UT$ and $TU$ are self-adjoint (e.g. $(UT)^* = UT)$ then U is the pseudoinverse of T i.e. $U$ is the linear trasformation defined like this, take $L$ to be the restriciton of $T$ on $N(T)^\perp$ and that has as codomain $R(T)$, so $U =L^{-1}(y),$ if $x \in R(T)$, and $U = 0$ otherwise.

Right now, your post is merely the statement of a question. It would be helpful if you could provide context for your question (as is generally expected), such as what you've tried so far.

By the way, are you familiar with the SVD-based formula for the pseudoinverse? Would it ok for us to assume that this is equivalent to your definition of the pseudoinverse in terms of the restrictions, or would you want a proof for that fact as well?

@BenGrossmann, yes i'am, i tried that way to prove it but i failed

Let $T^{\dagger}$ represent the pseudoinverse. Since $UT$ and $T^{\dagger}T$ are both self-adjoint, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
UT &= (UT)^* = T^*U^*=(TT^{\dagger}T)^*U^*=(T(T^{\dagger}T))^*U^*\\
&= (T^{\dagger}T)^*T^*U^* = T^{\dagger}T(UT)^* = T^{\dagger}(TUT)\\
&= T^{\dagger} T.
\end{align*}$$
A similar computation shows that $TU=TT^{\dagger}$.
Then
$$U = UTU = (T^{\dagger}T)U = T^{\dagger}(TU) = T^{\dagger}TT^{\dagger}=T^{\dagger}.$$

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to PSQs & dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

Here's an alternative approach using the SVD-based characterization of the MP-pseudoinverse. I will treat $T$ and $U$ as if they are matrices, but everything I say here can be framed in terms of operators over an inner product space.
Suppose that $T$ has SVD $T = P\Sigma Q$, where $P,Q$ are orthogonal matrices. Write
$$
\Sigma = \pmatrix{\Sigma_0 & 0\\0 & 0},
$$
where $\Sigma$ has the same shape as $T$ and $\Sigma_0$ is square with shape $r \times r$ ($r$ being equal to the rank of $T$). Let $\Phi = PUQ$ (so that $U = P^*\Phi Q^*$). Verify that your conditions over $T,U$ imply that
$$
\Sigma \Phi \Sigma = \Sigma\\
\Phi \Sigma \Phi = \Phi\\
(\Phi \Sigma)^* = \Phi \Sigma\\
(\Sigma \Phi)^* = \Sigma \Phi.
$$
The statement to be proved amounts to showing that
$$
\Phi = \pmatrix{\Sigma_0^{-1} & 0\\0 & 0}.
$$
With that in mind, partition $\Phi$ into the block-matrix
$$
\Phi = \pmatrix{A & B\\C & D}
$$
With block-matrix multiplication, $\Sigma = \Sigma \Phi \Sigma$ gives us
$$
\pmatrix{\Sigma_0 A \Sigma_0 & 0\\
0 & 0} = \pmatrix{\Sigma_0 & 0\\0&0},
$$
which allows us to deduce that $A = \Sigma_0^{-1}$. In terms of the original problem, we have deduced the behavior of $U$ over $N(T)^\perp$.
$\Sigma \Phi$ is equal to
$$
\Sigma \Phi = \pmatrix{\Sigma_0 & 0\\0 & 0}
\pmatrix{\Sigma_0^{-1} & B\\C & D} = \pmatrix{I & \Sigma_0 B\\0 & 0}.
$$
So, the fact that this matrix is self-adjoint tells us that $\Sigma_0 B = 0$, hence that $C = 0$. In terms of the original problem, this amounts to deducing that the restriction of $T$ to $N(T)$ has its image contained within $R(T)^\perp$.
Similarly, the fact that $\Phi \Sigma $ is self-adjoint tells us that $B = 0$. In terms of the original problem, this amounts to deducing that the restriction of $U^*$ to $N(T^*) = R(T)^\perp$ has its image contained within $R(T^*)^\perp = N(T)$.
Finally, $\Phi = \Phi \Sigma \Phi$ gives us
$$
\pmatrix{\Sigma_0^{-1} & 0\\0 & D} 
=  \pmatrix{\Sigma_0^{-1} & 0\\0 & D}\pmatrix{\Sigma_0&0\\0&0} \pmatrix{\Sigma_0^{-1} & 0\\0 & D} =
\\
\pmatrix{\Sigma_0^{-1} & 0\\ 0 & 0}.
$$
That is, we have $D = 0$. Thus, we have concluded that $\Phi$ has the required form, and the conclusion follows.
